# How to capture a tranfer event in oninitialize hook?

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, transfer

I have a custom pallet and i need to caputre and store all the transfer performed by root origin account. How can i implement it? An idea  i thought was capture the transfer event on oninitalize hook and add it to the storage of my custom pallet. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Eg: how will it be used?

Answer (score 0):

Events are meant as one-way communication with the external world. The runtime itself should never rely on them nor try to access them.

An alternative approach is to create a new root-only extrinsic that does the transfer and stores the fact that it happend. Otherwise it would be possible to modify the `Balances` pallet and add a hook for this case, but it is quite the niche thing.